# How to merge +alloc and -init?

Tags: objective-c, methods, nsobject

I am writing a method for a subclass of NSObject that merges the common NSObject methods "+alloc" and "-init". This is to save time when creating instances of a class.

(This subclass is also an abstract class. It is like a replacement for subclassing NSObject, so the method must be compatible with subclassing.)

For a method "make", is this the best way of writing it:

```
+(id)make
{
    id newObject = [[self.class alloc] init];

    return newObject;
}
```

If there is a better way, what would it be?

Thanks

Comment: For reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I assume that by "save time when creating instances of a class" you mean "save time typing", not "save some CPU cycles", because the class method way is actually slower.

Comment: Inside a class method, `self` is the class, and `[self class]` is unecessary. This can simply be written `return [[self alloc] init];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The better way is to just use `+new`, which already exists :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use `[self.class new]` which is the same thing as calling `[[self.class alloc] init]`

Comment: Inside a class method, `self` _is_ the class, and `[self class]` is unecessary.

Answer (score 2):

I find `new` works really well.

```
SomeObject *object = [SomeObject new];
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to make simple:

```
id newObject = [[self alloc] init];
```

you can replace it with:

```
id newObject = [self new];
```

But remeber that in many defined objects you can use other initializers, then you need to use:

```
...alloc] init...]
```

structure.